# How to use Mirth to insert data in SQL Server database from xml file

Tags: sql-server, xml, mirth, ccd, hl7-v3

I want to use Mirth to get data from XML file (CCD) and put its, in my SQL Server database.

So I have install Mirth connect administrator on my pc, then I have just created a new Channel with Source XML file, and to Destination my SQL server database. I have also selected table of my database, and automatically, Mirth have created this query:

```
INSERT INTO CLINICAL_DOC_Problems (Id, IdRoot, IdExtension, IdObservationRoot, IdObservationExtension, EffectiveTime, EffectiveTimeMin, EffectivTimeMax, CodeSystem, Code, CodeSystemStatus, CodeStatus, IdSection)
VALUES (, , , , , , , , , , , , )
```

Now the problem is this, the section (that I want insert in my database) of my CCD document (file .xml) have this structures:

```
<component>
<section>
    <templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.11'/> <!-- Problem section template -->
    <code code="11450-4" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1"/> 
    <entry typeCode="DRIV">
        <act classCode="ACT" moodCode="EVN">
            <templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.27'/> <!-- Problem act template -->
            <id root="6a2fa88d-4174-4909-aece-db44b60a3abb"/>
            <entryRelationship typeCode="SUBJ">
                <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                    <templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.28'/> <!-- Problem observation template -->
                    <id root="d11275e7-67ae-11db-bd13-0800200c9a66"/>
                    <code code="ASSERTION" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.4"/>                 
                    <effectiveTime><low value="1950"/></effectiveTime>
                    <value xsi:type="CD" code="195967001" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" displayName="Asthma"/>
                    <entryRelationship typeCode="REFR">
                        <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                            <templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.50'/> <!-- Problem status observation template -->
                            <code code="33999-4" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" displayName="Status"/>
                            <value xsi:type="CE" code="55561003" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" displayName="Active"/>
                        </observation>
                    </entryRelationship>
                </observation>
            </entryRelationship>
        </act>  
    </entry>
    <entry typeCode="DRIV">
        <act classCode="ACT" moodCode="EVN">
            <templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.27'/> <!-- Problem act template -->
            <id root="ec8a6ff8-ed4b-4f7e-82c3-e98e58b45de7"/>
            <entryRelationship typeCode="SUBJ">
                <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                    <templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.28'/> <!-- Problem observation template -->
                    <id root="ab1791b0-5c71-11db-b0de-0800200c9a66"/>
                    <code code="ASSERTION" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.4"/>
                    <value xsi:type="CD" code="233604007" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" displayName="Pneumonia"/>
                    <entryRelationship typeCode="REFR">
                        <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                            <templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.50'/> <!-- Problem status observation template -->
                            <code code="33999-4" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" displayName="Status"/>
                            <value xsi:type="CE" code="413322009" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" displayName="Resolved"/>
                        </observation>
                    </entryRelationship>
                </observation>
            </entryRelationship>
        </act>
    </entry>
</section>
</component>
```

As you can see, there are two tag

> entry typeCode="DRIV"

I want to insert in my database as many records as entry tag.
In this example, I should to insert in my database 2 records.

Comment: You have two problems or illness if you like here both referring to the same patient. So basically you have to iterate and use the code in the answer below to insert each illness separately.

Comment: Off-topic: I wonder why "value" data type of the problem status template is CE. I saw it before but it does not make sense since no alternative coding is or will be provided. The CD data type should work in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like the following in a JavaScript writer. I prefer the JavaScript writer over the Database Writer because you've got a lot more flexibility and can call all of the same native Mirth Java from the JavaScript.

If you pass your XML (from a File Reader, if I understand correctly...) from your source to your destination, set the destination type as a JavaScript writer, and then iterate through your objects like so:

```
var dbConn;
try {
    dbConn = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createConnection(driver, address, username, password);
    var xml = new XML(connectorMessage.getEncodedData());
    for(var i = 0; i < xml.section.entry.length(); i++) {
        if(xml.section.entry[i].@typeCode == 'DRIV') {
            var myData = xml.section.entry[i].act;
            var myQuery = '';
            //do something with myVar to get a query...
            dbConn.executeCachedQuery(myQuery);
        }
    }
} catch (ex) {
    //handle any exceptions...
}
```

Iteration through XML is done using E4X: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/E4X_tutorial